# home page redirect loop after update to 4.8

Tags: redirect, htaccess, directory

We have a WP site in a subdirectory with a URL akin to https://example.com/m/ after upgrading from WP 4.4.2 to 4.8 the front page generates a redirect loop: never-ending 301 redirect to /m/

The .htaccess is unchanged; I can reset to my previous commit and the front page works again.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#If request doesn't have a . in it and isn't terminated with a slash redirect to trailing slash.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/m/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any suggestions for where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Its not multisite

home and siteurl are set the same; https://example.com/m

Other permalinks work; only the front page has the loop.

Comment: If .htaccess is unchanged, what changed between the previous commit and now? New plugins? New content?

Comment: This `.htaccess` file is presumably located at `/m/.htaccess`? But if it is, then the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ `/index.php` would seem to be incorrect? Or do you have additional `.htaccess` files (in the document root)?

Comment: @WebElaine, the change is the update to WP Core from 4.4.2 to 4.8 so wp-load.php, wp-settings.php, wp-admin/, wp-includes/, etc.  No changes to wp-content/.

Comment: Requests to /m/ are forwarded to the doc root where WP and this .htaccess are from a load balancer (f5).